# Plotting "mirror curve" to the original curve ("y" values are good, "x" values do not match)

Tags: r, plot

**Graphically:**

The red curve is the original curve, the result of the regression. The blue curve is the monotonic version of the red curve. The thing is that it is increasing instead of decreasing! How can I "turn" this blue curve to fit to the red one?

```
## data
x <- c(1.009648,1.017896,1.021773,1.043659,1.060277,1.074578,1.075495,1.097086,1.106268,1.110550,1.117795,1.143573,1.166305,1.177850,1.188795,1.198032,1.200526,1.223329,1.235814,1.239068,1.243189,1.260003,1.262732,1.266907,1.269932,1.284472,1.307483,1.323714,1.326705,1.328625,1.372419,1.398703,1.404474,1.414360,1.415909,1.418254,1.430865,1.431476,1.437642,1.438682,1.447056,1.456152,1.457934,1.457993,1.465968,1.478041,1.478076,1.485995,1.486357,1.490379,1.490719)
y <- c(0.5102649,0.0000000,0.6360097,0.0000000,0.8692671,0.0000000,1.0000000,0.0000000,0.4183691,0.8953987,0.3442624,0.0000000,0.7513169,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.1291901,0.4936121,0.7565551,1.0085108,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.1655482,0.0000000,0.1473168,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.1875293,0.4918018,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.8101771,0.6853480,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.4068802,1.1061434,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.6391678)
fit1 <- c(0.5102649100,0.5153380934,0.5177234836,0.5255544980,0.5307668662,0.5068087080,0.5071001179,0.4825657520,0.4832969250,0.4836378194,0.4842147729,0.5004039310,0.4987301366,0.4978800742,0.4978042478,0.4969807064,0.5086987191,0.4989497612,0.4936121200,0.4922210302,0.4904593166,0.4775197108,0.4757040857,0.4729265271,0.4709141776,0.4612406896,0.4459316517,0.4351338346,0.4331439717,0.4318664278,0.3235179189,0.2907908968,0.1665721429,0.1474035158,0.1443999345,0.1398517097,0.1153991839,0.1142140393,0.1022584672,0.1002410843,0.0840033244,0.0663669309,0.0629119398,0.0627979240,0.0473336492,0.0239237481,0.0238556876,0.0084990298,0.0077970954,0.0000000000,-0.0006598571)
fit2 <- c(-0.0006598571,0.0153328298,0.0228511733,0.0652889427,0.0975108758,0.1252414661,0.1270195143,0.1922510501,0.2965234797,0.3018551305,0.3108761043,0.3621749370,0.4184150225,0.4359301495,0.4432114081,0.4493565757,0.4510158144,0.4661865431,0.4744926045,0.4766574718,0.4796937554,0.4834718810,0.4836125426,0.4839450098,0.4841092849,0.4877317306,0.4930561638,0.4964939389,0.4970089201,0.4971376528,0.4990394601,0.5005881678,0.5023814257,0.5052125977,0.5056691690,0.5064254338,0.5115481820,0.5117259449,0.5146054557,0.5149729419,0.5184178197,0.5211542908,0.5216215426,0.5216426533,0.5239797875,0.5273573222,0.5273683002,0.5293994824,0.5295130266,0.5306236672,0.5307303109)

## picture
plot(x, y)
lines(x, fit1, col=2)  # red curve
lines(x, fit2, col=4)  # blue curve
```

[image: pic]

```
lines(x, fit2[length(fit2):1])
```

This, of course, does not work due to the structure of X values.

**Methodologically:**

The object "fit2" is the output of the function rearrangement(). It is always monotonically increasing. So in the other words, I am not sure how to match values *x* to *y*.

```
library(Rearrangement)
fit2 <- rearrangement(x=as.data.frame(x), y=fit1)
```

Comment: How about `lines(min(x) + cumsum(c(0, rev(diff(x)))), rev(fit2))`

Comment: I really don't understand. The blue starts at (1,0) now. Where should it start? What's wrong with `lines(x, fit2[length(fit2):1])` exactly?

Comment: @MrFlick `x` doesn't increase in constant intervals

Comment: It's not a good idea to edit questions to ask additional questions. If something new as come up as a result of answering this problem, it's better to post a new question (possibly referencing this one; but make the new question self contained).

Comment: You're right. This question has been already answered reading the title of the question. Fixed!

Comment: I edited my answer. Your problem is not that you need a 'mirror' of your curve, it is that rearrangement returns something monotonically *increasing*. Since your data are decreasing, you need to do `fit 3 <- rearangement(x, - fit1)`. And then your result is `-fit3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Better way to deal with your problem:

Since your curve is monotonically decreasing, and `rearrangement` only returns monotonically increasing curves:

```
## rearrange the negative fit1
fit3 <- rearrangement(x=as.data.frame(x), y = - fit1)

## plot the negative rearranged fit3
plot(x, y)
lines(x, -fit3); points(x, -fit3, col=2)
lines(x, fit2); points(x, fit2, col=3)
```

[image]

So no fancy ´diff´ rearrangements for plotting is needed. The x values you get in `fit3` are the same from your data and `fit1`.

---

Another approach under the assumption that you have an object `fit` that can be used with `predict` (if for example you used something like `glm` to do the regression):

```
## New x data, equidistant
newx <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 1.5, 0.01))

## Predict using the fitted model 
pr <- predict(fit, type = "response", newdata = newx)

## Make the result monotonic
re <- rearrangement(x = newx, y = pr)

## Plot reversing the order of `newx`
lines(rev(newx$x), re)
```

Hope it helps,

alex

Comment: I used the conditional quantile functions to fit the model. But predict() can be useful in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why we can't just reverse `y` is that the intervals along your `x` aren't constant.

Essentially what you need to do, then, is to reverse not only `y`, but also the vector of gap widths between successive pairs of `x` values. We can do the latter with:

```
rev(diff(x))
```

We then just need to get their cumulative sum and add the minimum `x` value, so that we have not the gap widths but the `x` values themselves:

```
min(x) + cumsum(c(0, rev(diff(x))))
```

These are then your new `x` values, which you can plot up:

```
lines(min(x) + cumsum(c(0, rev(diff(x)))), rev(fit2))
```

[image]

Comment: Really helpful, thank you! But I still miss something... The new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197181/how-to-find-y-values-of-the-already-estimated-monotone-function-of-the-non-mon

Comment: As we solved three different problems in two questions, at the end, I marked the other answer as the right one. One more time, this is useful!